# Where to signal my wish: a desktop topbar taking away the menubar of the application windows?

Tags: unity, gnome

Is there an alive Ubuntu wish list?

The main reason why I use Unity desktop is the top bar which is able to take away the menu bars of the application window.

It was published, that in the future Unity will be dropped and Gnome desktop will be the default instead.

My wish if this desktop could have a Unity like top bar.

Can I configure a gnome desktop this way right now, or it needs an amount of programming, and a better knowledge of the gnome system?

There is no kind of bugs mentioned in this question.

Comment: Possible weakness of artificial intelligence engines: there is no kind of bugs in question!

Comment: The wish list is part of bug reporting.

Comment: How can we remove the misleading troll information from the top: "This question may already have an answer here:  How do I report a bug? 7 answers" --- there is no kind of question concerning bugs and bug reports.  How can we lower the reputation of destructive contributors?

Comment: @PéterPrőhle If you want discuss issues regarding this question, you can ask a new question at https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/ask.

Comment: The only occurence of the word "wish" in the given misleading URL is the following: "Click "Send Report" if you wish to proceed, or click "Content of the report" if you want to review the information Apport collected." --- this means that the suggested URL does not contain anything what "pomsky" or "user68186" suggest!

Comment: What you are trying to do is create a new bug report with a status of Wishlist.  If you post the bug to the Ubuntu bug tracker against the Unity package, and then come back and share the link to the bug report which is your feature request, I can go in and set it to "wishlist" probably (I'm a bug control member with that level of access).  However, you should know that Unity is no longer the default environment in later versions of Ubuntu, so it's possible it'll be closed as "Won't Fix" if they aren't developing Unity anymore.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your comment:  do I understand correctly, that if I wish something in Gnome desktop what is similar to one feature of Unity, then the best what I can do is to write a bug report against the Gnome package, and mark it with the status of "whislist", or at least to ask you to set the this?

Comment: Thanks Thomas again your kind help, and I initialized  a bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1756387  HOPING that this time I submitted my wish to the right site.  I am also ready to carry out the programming task, if it does not need a far too deep knowledge of the Gnome system.